# OpenCV 3 with contribution matlab module build fail

Tags: matlab, opencv, ubuntu, opencv3.0

I am having problems with building OpenCV 3 and the contribution matlab module,

I build it using:

```
cmake -D MATLAB_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin -DOPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/home/me/OpenCV/opencv/opencv_contrib-master/modules /home/me/OpenCV/opencv -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON   ..
```

However, it fails with a few modules including matlab, which is what I need at the moment.

Although it does find the mex it does not generate/build and shows it under   Unavailable modules.

I appreciate any ideas on what might be the cause and how to fix it. Thanks!

```
  Matlab:
--     mex:                         /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin/mex

-- Could NOT find Doxygen (missing:  DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE) 
-- To enable PlantUML support, set PLANTUML_JAR environment variable or pass -DPLANTUML_JAR=<filepath> option to cmake
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python2.7 (found suitable version "2.7.6", minimum required is "2.7") 
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python3.4 (found suitable version "3.4", minimum required is "3.4") 
-- Could NOT find PythonLibs (missing:  PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found suitable exact version "3.4.0")
-- Could NOT find Matlab (missing:  MATLAB_ARCH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/cmake/OpenCVFindMatlab.cmake I don't think `MATLAB_ROOT_DIR` should contain `/bin` since on line 139 they do `${MATLAB_ROOT_DIR}/bin`

You also shouldn't need to set `MATLAB_ROOT_DIR` at all since that script explicitly checks /usr/local for matlab on line 63 with`set(SEARCH_DIRS_ /Applications /usr/local /opt/local /usr /opt)`

Comment: well, alright. I am working on two stations and it was not able to find Matlab with the other computer, so I just kept it. Not much changes when I run without explicitly declaring the Matlab path. I just did actually.

I wonder what (missing:  MATLAB_ARCH) is.